# Microdata: How can i show hierarchy of offer category

Tags: html, microdata

I have offer of product, on my website, which is in some_category > subcategory > another_subcategory. How can I show this hierarchy with microdata?

Comment: Are you using `http://schema.org/Offer`? If so, you may add the tag [tag:schema.org] to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Schema.org/Offer](http://schema.org/Offer) has property *category* of in fact any type (*PhysicalActivityCategory or Text or Thing*) that allows you to do so. 
Description of the property says

> A category for the item. Greater signs or slashes can be used to
>   informally indicate a category hierarchy.

So I guess it would be something like

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <span itemprop="category">
  some_category > subcategory > another_subcategory
  </span>
</div>
```